# Cálculo en C# con resultado "infinito"

Tags: c#

Buenas,

Soy nuevo en esto. Estoy aprendiendo con los vídeos de MVC. Y con algunos recursos como guía de otras páginas. Y me surgió una laguna con respecto a un ejercicio que saqué de esta página: [1.8. Ejercicios con Formulas
Ejercicios con Formulas](http://programandoconcsharp.blogspot.com.ar/2013/10/18-ejercicios-con-formulas.html) resulta que aplicando este código:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, y, z;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de X.");
        x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de Y,");
        y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        z = (2.0 * x * x - 9.0 * x + 6.0) / ((y - 2.0) * (y * 3.0));

        Console.WriteLine("El valor de Z es:" + z);
        Console.Write("Presiona la tecla ENTER para continuar.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto después de darle las instrucciones me dice que el resultado es infinito. ¿Es posible? Lo pregunto desde la ignorancia.

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Analicemos la fórmula matemáticamente:

```
z = (2.0 * x * x - 9.0 * x + 6.0) / ((y - 2.0) * (y * 3.0));
```

reemplazemos

```
a = (2.0 * x * x - 9.0 * x + 6.0)
b = ((y - 2.0) * (y * 3.0))
```

por lo tanto

```
z = a / b
```

En una división de este tipo los casos interesantes serán cuando el numerador (`a`) o el denominador (`b`) sea(n) igual a 0

Tenemos los siguientes casos:

### Si `a == 0 || a == -0`  y `b != 0`

Entonces:

```
z == 0/b || z == -0/b
z == 0 || z == -0
```

En este caso z será 0

### Si `b == 0` y `1 != 0`

```
z == a/0 || z == a/-0 
z == ∞ || z == -∞
```

En estos casos puede dar `Double.PositiveInfinity` (∞) o `Double.NegativeInfinity` (-∞) respectivamente

### Si `a == 0 y b == 0`

```
z = 0/0
z = NaN
```

En este caso el resultado sería `Double.Nan`

Más información sobre [Double.PositiveInfinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx), [Double.NegativeInfinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx) y [Double.NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

En C# sí es posible.  Cuando haces cálculos aritméticos utilizando los tipos `double` o `float` existen algunos resultados especiales:

- Un número positivo entre cero (`N / 0`): `Infinity` (infinito positivo)
- Un número negativo entre cero (`-N / 0`): `-Infinity` (infinito negativo)
- Cero entre cero (`0 / 0`): `NaN` (*Not a Number*, no es un número válido)

Por lo tanto es posible que en la fórmula que usaste hayas obtenido 0 en el denominador de la fracción dependiendo de que valores ingresaste para X e Y, es por eso que el resultado es "infinito".